# TextView data binding for android:drawableBottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I am inflating layout for `TabLayout` with data binding inside my `Activity` class. And in that I am stuck with the data binding for `android:drawableBottom` inside `TextView`. My layout code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<data>

    <variable
        name="item"
        type="<package-name>.HomeTabItem"/>

</data>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="@={item.name}"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:drawableBottom="<What I have to-do here>"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_18" />
</layout>
```

The java code for binding inside the `Activity` class is as follows:

```
private void setTabsLayoutItems() {

    String tabItems[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.home_tab_items);
    TypedArray tabItemsDrawable = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.home_tab_items_drawable);

    for (int i = 0; i < tabItems.length; i++) {

        CustomTabBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.custom_tab, tabLayout, false);

        int id = tabItemsDrawable.getResourceId(i, -1);

        HomeTabItem obj = new HomeTabItem();
        obj.setName(tabItems[i]);
        obj.setIcon(id);
        binding.setItem(obj);
        View cropsTab = binding.getRoot();

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(cropsTab));
    }

    tabItemsDrawable.recycle();

}
```

`HomeTabItem` class is as follows:

```
public class HomeTabItem extends BaseObservable {

    private String name;

    private int icon;

    @Bindable
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        notifyPropertyChanged(com.sdei.farmx.BR.name);
    }

    @Bindable
    public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
        notifyPropertyChanged(com.sdei.farmx.BR.icon);
    }

}
```

Comment: android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_search"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set the iconID directly, like this:

```
android:drawableBottom="@{item.icon}"
```

If it does not work, you will have to create custom binding to set it. To do so, create a final class called Bindings and add the follow method:

```
@BindingAdapter({"icon"})
    public static void icon(TextView view, int iconId) {
       view.setCompoundDrawables(null,null,null, view.getContext().getDrawable(iconId));  
}
```

And call it in your layout:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="@={item.name}"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:icon="@{item.icon}"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_18" />
</layout>
```

Comment: final class?   Can you explain it more?

Comment: Is Just a simple class with this name